# Intune policies through JSON (oData) template

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, intune

I am trying to create a JSON template to create the Intune (based on Office 365) policies through Graph api. I am able to create policies for some of the URIs like terms and conditions but others. I tried creating for odata

## microsoft.graph.iosEasEmailProfileConfiguration

it failed giving error 400.
i would like to know if it is working for anyone and how

Answer (score 0):

If you get 400 errors in MS Graph API you can crete a case with Azure support.

I haven't tried the one you mention. But I have figured out a couple of them, after banging my head in the wall for some weeks with the poor Microsoft Graph API documentation.

**Compliance policies:**

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicies

```
   {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.androidCompliancePolicy",
    "displayName": "Android",
    "passwordRequired": true,
    "passwordMinimumLength": 4,
    "passwordRequiredType": "numericComplex",
    "passwordMinutesOfInactivityBeforeLock": 15,
    "storageRequireEncryption": true,
    "scheduledActionsForRule":[{"ruleName":"Mark device noncompliaant","scheduledActionConfigurations":[{"actionType":"block","gracePeriodHours":72,"notificationTemplateId":""}]}]
    }
```

**Device Configuration policies:**

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations

```
{
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.androidGeneralDeviceConfiguration",
            "description": "",
            "displayName": "Device restriction - Android",
            "passwordBlockFingerprintUnlock": false,
            "passwordBlockTrustAgents": false,
            "passwordExpirationDays": null,
            "passwordMinimumLength": 4,
            "passwordMinutesOfInactivityBeforeScreenTimeout": 15,
            "passwordPreviousPasswordBlockCount": null,
            "passwordSignInFailureCountBeforeFactoryReset": 11,
            "passwordRequiredType": "numericComplex",
            "passwordRequired": true,
            "storageRequireDeviceEncryption": true
}
```

I have also figured out branding, groups, setting MDM authority, setting update ring and adding windows hello settings.

But I cannot figure out how to assign compliance policies to groups.
The examples in the MS Graph API documentation just throws an error.

I also cannot find where in Graph API i can do condidtional access in Intune and how I control device settings in Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a **POST** to **deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations** with following sample payload:

```
{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "displayName": "profile name",
    "description": "profile description",
    "scopeTags": [],
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.iosEasEmailProfileConfiguration",
    "blockMovingMessagesToOtherEmailAccounts": false,
    "blockSendingEmailFromThirdPartyApps": false,
    "blockSyncingRecentlyUsedEmailAddresses": false,
    "durationOfEmailToSync": "userDefined",
    "requireSmime": false,
    "requireSsl": true,
    "hostName": "outlook.microsoft.com",
    "accountName": "Account name",
    "usernameSource": "userPrincipalName",
    "emailAddressSource": "userPrincipalName",
    "authenticationMethod": "usernameAndPassword"
}
```